# Kendo UI Gantt chart task lable change

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to change Kendo UI Gantt title. i found one demo code, but it was not working

```
 <div id="gantt"></div>
<script>
$("#gantt").kendoGantt({
  dataSource: [{
     id: 1,
     orderId: 0,
     parentId: null,
     title: "Task1",
     start: new Date("2014/6/17 9:00"),
     end: new Date("2014/6/17 11:00")
  }],
  messages: {
    views: {
      editor: {
        editorTitle:"Edit Task"
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to change the label on Gantt bars ?
I want some info on left side tree and other info on bars is it possible ? 
parent child relation is not retaining if i add gantt columns other than title.

```
    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: { from: "ID", type: "number" },
                            descr : { from : "DESCR", type: "string"},
                            orderId: { from: "ORDERID", type: "number", validation: { required: true } },
                            parentId: { from: "PARENTID", type: "number", defaultValue: null, validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { from: "START", type: "date" },
                            end: { from: "END", type: "date" },
                            Title: { from: "TITLE", defaultValue: "", type: "string" },
                            percentComplete: { from: "PERCENTCOMPLETE", type: "number" },
                            summary: { from: "SUMMARY", type: "boolean" },
                            expanded: { from: "EXPANDED", type: "boolean", defaultValue: true }
                        }
                    }

 var gantt = $("#gantt").kendoGantt({
                dataSource: tasksDataSource,

                views: [
                    "day",
                    "week",
                    "month",
                    { type: "year", selected: true },
                ],
                columns: [
                    { field: "descr", title: "Descr", editable: true, sortable: true },

                ],
                height: 400,

                showWorkHours: false,
                showWorkDays: false,

                snap: false
            }).data("kendoGantt");


            var gantt1 = $("#gantt1").kendoGantt({
                dataSource: tasksDataSource1,
                views: [
                    "day",
                    "week",
                    "month",
                    { type: "year", selected: true },
                ],
                columns: [
                    { field: "title", title: " ", editable: true, sortable: true },

                ],
                height: 400,

                showWorkHours: false,
                showWorkDays: false,

                snap: false
            }).data("kendoGantt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting uppercase:

```
dataSource: [{
     ID: 1,
     OrderId: 0,
     ParentId: null,
     Title: "Task1",
     Start: new Date("2014/6/17 9:00"),
     End: new Date("2014/6/17 11:00")
  }],
```

EDIT:

Answering to your comment:
Define columns definition:

```
dataSource: [{
     ID: 1,
     OrderId: 0,
     ParentId: null,
     Title: "Task1",
     Start: new Date("2014/6/17 9:00"),
     End: new Date("2014/6/17 11:00"),
     Description: "Some longer description"
  }],
  columns: [
        { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: 60 },
        { field: "Title", title: "Title", editable: true, sortable: true },
        { field: "Description", title: "Description", width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true }
    ],
```

Comment: I want some info on left side tree and other info on bars is it possible ?

Comment: i don't want to display title column on bars.. without title column parent child relationship is not retaining.

Comment: So just delete `Id` and `Title` from columns definition. Then `Title` will be label for right side and Description for left side